# when I am doing Form Validations in Struts I am Getting org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorException

Tags: struts

```
When I am Doing Form validations In Struts I am Getting Exception:
```

org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorException:
      No such validation method:
      org.apache.struts.validator.FieldChecks.validateRequired
      (java.lang.Object, org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction,
      org.apache.commons.validator.Field, org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors, 
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
       at org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction.loadValidationMethod
        (ValidatorAction.java:604)
    at org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction.executeValidationMethod
         (ValidatorAction.java:532)
    at org.apache.commons.validator.Field.validateForRule(Field.java:796)
    at org.apache.commons.validator.Field.validate(Field.java:876)
    at org.apache.commons.validator.Form.validate(Form.java:288)
    at org.apache.commons.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:351)
    at org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorForm.validate(ValidatorForm.java:110)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processValidate 
         (RequestProcessor.java:927)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:204)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
         (ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
         (ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke
         (StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke
         (StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke
          (AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke
         (StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process
          (AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process
         (AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run
         (JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2):

I am also getting the same error while I try to submit a form. I found that this error could be the result of having a validation-rules.xml file from one version of struts, but a struts.jar file from another version of struts. Check your installation and make absolutely sure that both of these files come from the same download. Also check that all other jar files in the WEB-INF/lib directory come from the same download.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<!DOCTYPE form-validation PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Commons Validator Rules Configuration 1.1.3//EN" "http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/dtds/validator_1_1_3.dtd">
```

To:

```
<!DOCTYPE form-validation PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Commons Validator Rules Configuration 1.3.0//EN" "http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/dtds/validator_1_3_0.dtd">
```