# org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorException: No such validation method

Tags: java, struts

```
org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorException: No such validation method: org.apache.struts.validator.FieldChecks.validateRequired(java.lang.Object, org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction, org.apache.commons.validator.Field, org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages, javax.servlet.http.HttpSer
```

when I work with struts1.3 I get above error. I found that it is because of version variation of validation-rules.xml and struts.jar but I make same version still I am getting same problem. Because of this validations not effect on form.

Would you please help me resolve this issue?

http://www.laliluna.de/download/struts-dynavalidatoraction-form-en.pdf

Just I had trial on dynavalidatoractionform by above link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088861/when-i-am-doing-form-validations-in-struts-i-am-getting-org-apache-commons-valid